# cardano-cli transaction with inline datum

Tags: cardano-cli

I already have utxos with inline datum sitting at a wallet address (not in a smart contract address):
[image: wallet utxos]

now I want to use this utxo in another transaction, in order to inspect it's datum, without spending the utxo:

```
cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
--babbage-era \
--tx-in fcb7f6692469d9a2eefb04e05241d3288aad4849303da5369465bb395cf9fe8c#1   
--tx-in-inline-datum-present
--tx-in {other utxo to be spent}
... some outputs ...
--tx-in-collateral {collateral utxo}
--protocol-params-file pparams.json
... and so on, the usual stuff
```

The thing is, once I call 'transaction submit' command, I get an error:

```
Invalid option `--tx-in'
```

I am 100% confident, that error is raised from inline datum related commands. What am I doing wrong? Maybe it is impossible to read inline datums from simple wallet addresses, only from validators (by also providing plutus scripts, datums, redeemers, etc.). Or maybe my cardano-cli syntax is wrong and I am missing something?

EDIT:
screenshots of the exact cardano-cli commands:
[image: failing syntax]

[image: correct syntax]

Comment: Can you screenshot your command and the error message exactly?

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 0):

solved, this helped: https://github.com/input-output-hk/Vasil-testnet/blob/main/reference-inputs-cip-31.md

problem was in syntax, referenced input must be provided with --read-only-tx-in-reference option